# Ajax doesn't post inline table edit

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I've got a table of which I'm trying to add inline-edit to, but I'm really new to ajax. The JQuery code itself works, I can see the td's changing into input fields but I'm having trouble with posting the data.

When I click away from the table td that I'm trying to edit, it's suppose to post the data. But when I do that and refresh the page, the generated table isn't updated nor can I see changes in the database. It doesn't display an error, it only refreshes the page.

**projectlist database table**

```
projectid | Klant

4         | mike

12        | peterson
```

**PHP**

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($resultaat, MYSQL_ASSOC)){
    $id = $row['projectid'];

    <tr id="<?php echo $id ?>" class="tredit">
        <form action="" method="post">
            <td>
                <span id="klant_<?php echo $id ?>" class="text"><?php echo $row["Klant"] ?></span>
                <input type="text" class="ip" id="klant_ip_<?php echo $id ?>" value="<?php echo $row["Klant"] ?>">
            </td>
        </form>
    </tr>
}
```

**Ajax**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".tredit").click(function(){
        var ID=$(this).attr('id');

        $("#klant_"+ID).hide();
        $("#klant_ip_"+ID).show();
    }).change(function(){
        var ID=$(this).attr('id');
        var first=$("#klant_ip_"+ID).val();
        var dataString = 'id='+ ID +'&Klant='+first;
        //alert(dataString);

        if(first.length > 0){
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "post_table.php",
                //data: dataString,
                data: dataString,
                cache: false,
                success: function(html){
                    $("#klant_"+ID).html(first);
                },
                error: function (request, error) {
                    console.log(arguments);
                    alert(" Can't do because: " + error);
                }
            });
        }else{
            alert('Input something');
        }
    });

    $(".ip").mouseup(function() {
        return false
    });

    $(document).mouseup(function(){
        $(".ip").hide();
        $(".text").show();
    });
});
```

**post_table.php**

```
<?php
    include('config.php');
    $klant = $_POST['Klant'];
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $query = "update projectlist set Klant='$klant' where id='$id'";
    mysql_query($query, $con);
?>
```

**Solution**

I got it working. It never ever occured to me to thoroughly check the `post_table.php`.

`where id='$id'` is wrong, it must be `where projectid='$id'`.

Comment: What does not work actually ? What can you see ? Isn't the database filled?

Comment: Is the Ajax request being triggered at all?

Comment: @M.M. It doesn't seem so. I added some more details to my question.

Comment: @Cr3aHal0 Nothing but page refresh is happening. I added some more details to my question.

Comment: Try to inspect requests and queries with tools such as Chrome Dev Tool (F12) which will provide you feedback on failed requests. It will notice you if there are some errors such as 500 (error server-side) or 404 (your URL is probably wrong)

Comment: You will need to establish first if the change event is being triggered. You might find console.log() (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/log) being quite useful for debugging JS.

Comment: use event.preventDefault();

Comment: @M.M. I've tried to use the console log, but I think I'm doing it wrong, it broke the entire javascript code and making it unreachable with Firebug. I placed it just above `if(first.length > 0){`

Comment: @Cr3aHal0 the log doesn't seem to report any errors.

Comment: try not to chane the click with the change event

Comment: Just echo your update query in post_table.php file and check if the values are getting posted or not... Also, check if your ajax call is happening even by putting some alert there...

Comment: @prembaranwal I've tried the alert approach and everything seems to work. But the `post_table.php` doesn't seem to echo anything.

Comment: @prembaranwal I even tried to echo `$klant` and `$id` but no results, could it be that the `post_table.php` is unreachable?

Comment: Do die('Hello');  at the top of your post_table.php file... Check if is printing Hello or not. If it is printing, means your ajax call is fine. Then there is some issue with data sending. Try sending data in JSON like this: 
    data : {"id":ID}
And add one more parameter in your ajax call as
    datatype: "json"

And check if data is getting posted or not.

If your die() statement doesn't work in your post_table.php file, means something is wrong with your ajax call only...

Comment: Do not echo only your variables, but add some hard coded string also with that... Because if your variables are not getting posted, then those values will be empty only and nothing will get print. So, try printing some string also there, say do echo 'Here';

Comment: If you put a "var_dump($_POST);" in post_table file, what do you see?

Comment: @Portekoi nothing. I've figured out that the fault lies in the ajax posting. Now I only need to fix that bug.

Comment: @prembaranwal See my updated ajax in the question. The error I got was "parseerror"

Comment: Is it the `$('.tredit').change()` that does not fire? Try `$('.tredit input').change()`

Comment: @diynevala No that works, I've deduced that the problem lies within in `$.ajax()`

Comment: @user3095385 : Just replace your data parameter with this: 
    data: { 'id' : ID, 'Klant' : first }

Rest everything is fine...

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".tredit").click(function(){
        var ID=$(this).attr('id');

        $("#klant_"+ID).hide();
        $("#klant_ip_"+ID).show();
    })

 $(".tredit").change(function(){
        var ID=$(this).attr('id');
        var first=$("#klant_ip_"+ID).val();
        var dataString = {"id":ID,"Klant":first};
        //alert(dataString);
        $("#klant_"+ID).html('<img src="load.gif" />');

        if(first.length > 0){
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "post_table.php",
                data: dataString,
                cache: false,
                success: function(html){
                    $("#klant_"+ID).html(first);
                }
            });
        }else{
            alert('Input something');
        }
    });

    $(".ip").mouseup(function() {
        return false
    });

    $(document).mouseup(function(){
        $(".ip").hide();
        $(".text").show();
    });
});
```

The php has to return something on the page

```
<?php
    include('config.php');
    $klant = $_POST['Klant'];
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $query = "update projectlist set Klant='$klant' where id='$id'";
    mysql_query($query, $con);
    echo "success";
?>
```

Comment: Isn't `{id:ID,Klant:first};` meant for `dataType: "json"`? If I add that, I get an parse error. But if I remove the json contenttype I don't get an error but nothing else happends.

Comment: try using  `dataType:"json"` and `data:JSON.stringify({id:ID,Klant:first}) `

Comment: Still seem to be getting a pars error. This is so annoying.

Comment: @user3095385 : Just replace your data parameter with this: data: { 'id' : ID, 'Klant' : first } Rest everything is fine... See my comment at the top...